# how to convert take a text from website using lxml?

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

Im making script for md5 decryption purposed , and the problem is when im take the feedback from the server is give me whole of the html page, how do i take certain tag on html with lxml? here the html that only what i want to take

```
</div><br>b2f21ccee13ffff12eec42e5ee981ea4 : <b>cahyadarma30</b><br><br>Trouvé en 0.031s<br><br>
```

Edited : Here the whole page script

```
<html class="gr__md5decrypt_net" lang="fr"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<meta name="Description" content="Crypter un mot en md5, ou décrypter un md5 en le comparant à notre base de données de <b>10,311,700,316</b> hashs uniques gratuitement.">
<meta name="Keywords" content="cassage md5 crypt encrypt decrypt hack crack hacking cracking sécurité informatique decrypter">  
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/includes/favicon.ico">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://md5decrypt.net/en/" hreflang="en-US">
<title>Md5 Encryption &amp; Decryption Gratuite - Plus de 10.000.000.000 hashs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.co.id/adsid/integrator.js?domain=md5decrypt.net" as="script"><script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101"></script><script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/r20160913/ca-pub-7320132219000404.js"></script><script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190401/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js" id="google_shimpl"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.co.id/adsid/integrator.js?domain=md5decrypt.net"></script><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=md5decrypt.net" as="script"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=md5decrypt.net"></script><link rel="preload" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190401/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js" as="script"></head>
<body onload="document.getElementbyId('hash_input').focus();" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/">Accueil</a></li>
        <li>
                <a href="#">Encrypt / Decrypt</a>
                <ul id="menu_decrypt">
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/" title="Décryption des hashs md5">Decryption Md5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Md4/" title="Décryption des hashs md4">Decryption Md4 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha1/" title="Décryption des hashs sha1">Decryption Sha1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha256/" title="Décryption des hashs sha256">Decryption Sha256</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha384/" title="Décryption des hashs sha384">Decryption Sha384</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha512/" title="Décryption des hashs sha512">Decryption Sha512</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Ntlm/" title="Décryption des hashs NTLM">Decryption Ntlm</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Xor/" title="Décryption cryptage XOR">Decryption Xor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Code-morse/" title="Décryption Code Morse">Decryption Code Morse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Leet-traducteur/" title="Leet speak traducteur">Leet traducteur</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Detecteur/" title="Détection type de hash">Détecteur de hash</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Bcrypt/" title="Encryption Bcrypt">Encryption Bcrypt</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Blowfish/" title="Encryption Blowfish">Encryption Blowfish</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Whirlpool/" title="Encryption Whirlpool">Encryption Whirlpool</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile_li"><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Outils-conversion/" title="Outils de conversion hexadécimal binaire base 64">Outils de conversion</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile_li"><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/about/" title="contactez moi">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile_li"><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/" title="Version française">Français</a></li>
                        <li class="mobile_li"><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/en/" title="English version">English</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Outils-conversion/" title="Outils de conversion hexadécimal binaire base 64">Outils de conversion</a></li>
        <li>
                <a href="#">Chiffres</a>
                <ul id="menu_cipher">
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Chiffre-gronsfeld/" title="Décryption du chiffrement de Gronsfeld">Decryption chiffre de Gronsfeld</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Chiffre-tritheme/" title="Décryption du chiffrement de Trithème">Decryption chiffre de Trithème</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Rot13/" title="Décryption du chiffrement ROT13">Decryption ROT13</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Cesar/" title="Décryption du chiffrement de César">Decryption chiffre de César</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Carre-polybe/" title="Décryption du carré de Polybe">Decryption Carré de Polybe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Chiffre-vigenere/" title="Encryption et décryption du chiffre de Vigenere">Decryption Chiffre de Vigenere</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Analyse-frequence-lettres/" title="Analyse fréquentiele">Analyse fréquentielle</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Téléchargements</a>
            <ul id="menu_download">
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/en/Password-cracking-wordlist-download/" title="Télécharger Md5decrypt awesome wordlist">Md5decrypt.net Free Wordlist</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Unfound/sorted_unfound_md5.txt.gz" title="Télécharger Md5 non trouvés" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://md5decrypt.net/Unfound/sorted_unfound_md5.txt.gz'); return false;">Liste Md5 non trouvés</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha1/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha1.txt.gz" title="Télécharger Sha1 non trouvés" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://md5decrypt.net/Sha1/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha1.txt.gz'); return false;">Liste Sha1 non trouvés</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha256/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha256.txt.gz" title="Télécharger Sha256 non trouvés" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://md5decrypt.net/Sha256/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha256.txt.gz'); return false;">Liste Sha256 non trouvés</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha384/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha384.txt.gz" title="Télécharger Sha384 non trouvés" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://md5decrypt.net/Sha384/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha384.txt.gz'); return false;">Liste Sha384 non trouvés</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Sha512/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha512.txt.gz" title="Télécharger Sha512 non trouvés" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://md5decrypt.net/Sha512/Unfound/sorted_unfound_sha512.txt.gz'); return false;">Liste Sha512 non trouvés</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Md4/Unfound/sorted_unfound_md4.txt.gz" title="Télécharger Md4 non trouvés" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://md5decrypt.net/Md4/Unfound/sorted_unfound_md4.txt.gz'); return false;">Liste Md4 non trouvés</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Api/" title="Api gratuite">API</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/about/" title="contactez moi">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/" title="Version française">FR</a>
        <span class="blanc">|</span></li>
        <li><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/en/" title="English version">EN</a></li></ul>

<div id="corps">
<h1 class="titre">Md5() <span class="vert">Encrypt</span> &amp; <span class="rouge">Decrypt</span></h1>
<span class="gplus"><a title="Partager via Google Plus" onclick="popUp=window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://md5decrypt.net', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400'); popUp.focus(); return false;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAA7DAAAOwwHHb6hkAAAAB3RJTUUH4QIPDDkK1CS8cQAAA6VJREFUOMutlG9oVXUYxz/POb9zzr1d9xc3FcstnW1tlb4wKEIlgvVmJpJCEUZvqleVIQVGLDF6sYhQaBCatBcqQjgT07LQstIhDsywMpkzCnVru/t7b3e75/c7v17cebfrZsvowDkvnuf3fM/3+f6e7yPd61bZKAz5fx9BRWFIpHVh3Np/qrnxKTwvhTGVz4UhNsxiI4MTuwPxvJuKQXwfESEay0wBEnCkkIwICmvBWopWN1L8+BpidQ2IHwcz2YV4PqIUw8cO0b9zx+S/jKGsaT0VL2+h972tjBw/OsnYW3Anla9tw2bH6N/9AWagj+LGJyh98hmcWJwonab3/W1kLpwj7LmGeGoKW5vvTFRhh87Clg8hMlx94yUyF86R7blK30c76N+5HSKDk0hQuu5prA4RpXKtG4PVIWiNjcwEe52TU4dgDGKNsck9u0i2tSJBLH8ZVmvu2v4x8fuWA9DX2sLQkXbEdSld+xSJFQ9jdYiqXIC/6G6yv11G9/8JIox3XURZozGjQ+A4BeKDZah9bx44/sAKhr/8DKwlqKklvvzBgtb96iX41Usm7sRDiePilpZPGzFRHukz301qNqcIcYRoPGRwfxujx49itWbOI49S0rSeoYP7+KuzI6fUyAgK1yWorkE8/6Z5FUxqFJsdR/wAk+zDmghsxFj3Jei6iDUaf2EVAONXukid+T5X6jo4ALF76vGrFs9gDEH8AID02VPYMDtR6CKel3v9HCHH8/MxXJUDVhXzKFmzAVw1OaPZLEWrHgNg9JtjpE59Pd2Ejkvm/FkG2lrJ/PRDYS7zy482WFqPuC7Dhz9h4MAe0JpY3f3M3/wWqdMn6Hm3GcSZZlsAoghrNOKqyQEQQS6vXWmLGpuI1S9Dza1EPD+neRAw8tVhrr+zBScWnxn0lvtEUFaHDB7cj/P5p6A8yjc8S6y2Iadrx7c5R90O6I0pQgRRCqs1UXoUm0nnk/M2b8VfVIU1+j8ARxZrDLgubnEpqc6O/O07iQTVu9opWt1428AqWFxDUL+MoKYO8TxsGJI530mw9F7ckjJwHea//jZ9JWUMHznw72XWyT6rk/0Mtu8l+/sVokw6Z4ogTsXzm0g8tDK/P/7Y9Bxjv/48u+YiyGjHSXu9+VVw3Wl5awxzN75A+cYXAUidPsm15lemu3QGYKe35c3CBTQ177ok9+1m+ItDuUVU24CNotl1sBYVVNXkd+otTpHtvoSNIiIdEq9tmJ0x8DdyzH0Ty2rz1QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="google plus share"></a></span>
<span class="fb"><a title="Partager via Facebook" onclick="popUp=window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://md5decrypt.net', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400'); popUp.focus(); return false;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="facebook share"></a></span>
<form action="https://md5decrypt.net/#answer" method="POST">
<textarea name="hash" rows="1" cols="40" id="hash_input" placeholder="Collez un ou plusieurs hashs (maximum 500)"></textarea><br>
<input id="captcha" type="text" name="captcha55987" placeholder="Email requis">
<input type="hidden" name="ahah55987" value="58302b7d8f8a11bc262ac61c7e7aac88">
<input type="submit" name="crypt" value="Crypter" class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="decrypt" value="Décrypter" class="submit">
<br>
</form>
<br><fieldset id="answer"><div id="ads_results">
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Md5decrypt - reload -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;min-width:320px;max-width:970px;width:100%;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7320132219000404" data-ad-slot="7703718571" data-ad-format="auto" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_0_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:970px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_0_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:970px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_0" name="aswift_0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0px;width:970px;height:90px;" __idm_frm__="118111600722" width="970" height="90" frameborder="0"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div><br>b2f21ccee13ffff12eec42e5ee981ea4 : <b>cahyadarma30</b><br><br>Trouvé en 0.031s<br><br>
<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- thematique - trouve -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block; height: 90px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7320132219000404" data-ad-slot="4380218742" data-ad-format="link" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:970px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:970px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0px;width:970px;height:90px;" __idm_frm__="118111600726" width="970" height="90" frameborder="0"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script><br>
</fieldset><br>
<div class="fieldsetContainer_alone">
<fieldset class="right_alone">
<h2 class="last_hash_text">À propos du Md5 :</h2><br>
<div id="pub_texte">
<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Md5decrypt - Texte2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7320132219000404" data-ad-slot="7437303524" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_2_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0px;width:336px;height:280px;" __idm_frm__="118111600728" width="336" height="280" frameborder="0"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>Le Md5 (<span style="font-style:italic;">Message Digest 5</span>) est une fonction 
cryptographique qui permet de "hasher" 
une séquence numérique en un <span style="font-style:italic;">hash md5</span> de 128 bits, soit 32 caractères, 
et ce peu importe la longueur de la séquence originale. Ce système cryptographique est irréversible, il n'est pas possible d'obtenir la séquence originale (de décrypter) en 
utilisant seulement le hash md5. 
La seule façon de décrypter le hash est donc de le comparer à une base contenant les hashs md5 et leur séquence correspondante. Ce site se sert d'une base de 
plus de 10.000.000.000 de hashs md5 pour vous proposer une séquence correspondante à votre hash afin de le décrypter. Une fonction de hachage de séquence 
(encryption md5) est aussi 
disponible, chaque mot crypté va rejoindre la 
base de données. Le dictionnaire utilisé provient de tous les dictionnaires (wordlists) que j'ai pu trouver sur internet, compilés, triés, puis élargis grâce à un script de ma fabrication. 
Après plusieurs jours de calculs, j'en suis arrivé à une base de données unique et pertinente.<br><br>
Le md5 n'est plus considéré comme sûr depuis un certain temps. En 2004 une collision complète a été découverte par des chercheurs chinois. Depuis cette date, les collisions 
sont de plus en plus facilitées notamment par l'amélioration de la puissance de traitement des ordinateurs. Il est maintenant possible de trouver une collision 
en md5 en moins de quelques minutes. Si vous voulez en apprendre plus sur les collisions md5, vous pouvez consulter <a href="http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/">ce lien</a>.
Il est maintenant conseillé d'utiliser le sha256, 512, bcrypt, scrypt ou whirlpool pour stocker vos mots de passe.<br>
Si toutefois vous souhaitez conserver le md5 comme fonction de hachage pour votre site, il est conseillé d'utiliser un "salt" pour le rendre plus difficile à cracker 
par brute-force (et par rainbow tables). Un salt est simplement une chaîne de caractère que l'on ajoute au mot de passe fourni par l'utilisateur pour le rendre plus compliqué à casser.
Par exemple, si on utilise le mot de passe "password", qui est évidemment très facile à casser. Il suffit de lui concaténer une chaîne de caractère aléatoire créee via une fonction en php 
par exemple. Imaginons une chaîne de caractère utilisant tous les caractères alphanumériques et de 14 caractères de long, par exemple a~/!c^12/*bn@(. Si on concatène ceci à 
"password", cela donne a~/!c^12/*bn@(password. Il est évident que ce mot de passe sera difficilement trouvable dans une base de données en ligne. Vous pouvez aussi 
séparer le salt en deux mots de taille égale et les concaténer en début et en fin de mot de passe par exemple. Par ailleurs, si vous cherchez une astuce pour créer un mot de 
passe simple à se souvenir en tant qu'utilisateur, mais aussi résistant au bruteforce et aux rainbow tables, vous pouvez utiliser une phrase complète. Par exemple 
jemesouviensdecemotdepassecestsur. Cela présente l'avantage d'être facile à se remémorer, et d'être très difficile à casser. Pour peu que vous ajoutiez une majuscule et un chiffre 
le mot de passe sera très difficile à cracker.
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
<span class="mentions_fr"><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/Mentions-legales/">Mentions légales </a></span>
<!--<span class="mentions_en"><a href="https://md5decrypt.net/en/Legal-mentions/">Legal mentions</a></span>-->
<span style="color: #333;font: 15px open sans, sans-serif;"> | 18,800,010 cracked hashes since 11/2015</span><span style="color: #333;font: 15px open sans, sans-serif;"> | There are 10,311,700,316 words in the database | </span><span class="mentions_fr"> <a href="https://md5decrypt.net/en/Password-cracking-wordlist-download/"> | Download Md5decrypt's Wordlist</a></span>
</iframe></html>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit, what "string" you wanna get? "b2f21ccee13ffff12eec42e5ee981ea4" ??  "cahyadarma30"??. And pls, post more complete HTML, cause the html you posted start with </div>

Comment: @Wonka no i want to get the cahyadarma30 because its the result of the decryption, the complete html is really long because it taking the whole page

Comment: ok, then post a bit more of the HTML code where the element is inside

Comment: @Wonka have adding the full html but deleted some of the bottom because character limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer, my variable s is the html string

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = YOUR_HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
b = soup.find("b")
print(b.text)
```

OUTPUT

```
cahyadarma30
```

Comment: `
md5.py:29: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 29 of the file md5.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor. `

Comment: you are right, i edit my answer. If the answer is fine, pls mark it as correct